# Trying to make a FAQ page with UIKIT. [HTML] [CSS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uikit

was trying to make a FAQ page on UIKIT, but I have this problem:

I want to make it open and close , but it only opens and closes instantly almost here's my code :

```css
**CSS looks like this:**

.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent.uk-active > a {
background: inherit;
color: inherit;
}

.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent.uk-active > a:hover,
.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent.uk-active > a:focus {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 color: #444;
 outline: none;
}


.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent .uk-nav-side > li > a {
 padding-left: 1em;
}

.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent .uk-nav-side > li.uk-active > a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/css/uikit.css" />
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/js/uikit.js"></script>

<div class="uk-width-1-6"></div>
 <div class="uk-width-medium">
  <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
   <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav="{multiple:true}">
    <li class="uk-parent uk-active">
     <a href="#"><p><h3><b>Sobre a ProjectD</b></h3></p></a>
      <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-side">
       <li class="uk-parent">
        <p>Nunc purus ipsum, molestie eu nisl vitae, malesuada dictum augue. Donec pharetra eu quam eget consectetur. Fusce faucibus sem et lectus iaculis euismod. Aliquam sodales sem vitae tincidunt tincidunt. In orci ex, ultrices at felis quis, faucibus elementum tortor. Fusce mi metus, viverra sed mi ornare, ultrices facilisis urna. Morbi ultrices sollicitudin nisi at viverra. Cras rhoncus eu tellus at hendrerit. Sed consequat, dolor ac facilisis tempor, nisi mauris rutrum sapien, ac sagittis tortor ipsum sed velit. Integer neque nisl, pulvinar sit amet cursus eu, iaculis ut sem. Proin scelerisque, lorem sit amet egestas ullamcorper, elit turpis hendrerit urna, non dictum odio urna ac odio. Nullam ut arcu sed lectus blandit fringilla. Sed vestibulum quis diam vitae rutrum. Nulla aliquet maximus dignissim. Aliquam condimentum interdum magna, in rhoncus enim hendrerit eu. Integer euismod et eros sit amet tincidunt.</p>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accordion](https://getuikit.com/docs/accordion) component for this problem.
With extra CSS:

```
    .uk-accordion-title::before{
     background-image: 'icon-url-here';}

    .uk-open>.uk-accordion-title::before {
     background-image: 'icon-url-here';}
```